# Problem about differentiability and continuity

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Suppose I have a question.

Find the values of a and b, if the function f is defined as,
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^{2}+3 x+a, x \leq 1 \\
b x+2, x>1
\end{array}\right.
$$

So, what my teacher asks me to do is this,
Calculate the $LHD$ and $RHD$ (Left hand derivative and Right hand derivative)

At $x=1$

$LHD$ is,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\quad \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(1-h)-f(1)}{-h} \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1+h^{2}-2 h+3-3 h-4-2+2}{-h} \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h^{2}-5 h}{-h} \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0}(5-h) \\
=5
\end{array}
$$
$f(1-h)$ means the case when $x < 1$, means I have to use $x^{2}+3 x+a$

And $f(1)$ means the same case, when $x \leq 1$
And $RHD$ is,

*Warning: this is the problem region*

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\quad \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{b+b h+2-b(1)-2}{h} \\
=b
\end{array}
$$

As they are given differentiable at $x=1$.

Equating them,

$LHD=RHD$

$b=5$
And uses continuity (equating $LHL$ and $RHL$ and $f(1)$) to find another equation and solve it to find $a$
Giving $a=3$, and $b=5$

Well, in the $RHD$ didn't he use the wrong case for $f(1)$, he should've use the case when $x \leq 1$, why the heck did he use $x>1$, and

Everyone is telling me the logic behind this is that we are calculating $RHD$, which means everything lies in the right neighbourhood of $1$ even $f(1)$, I get the logic but that is still breaking rules of math,

What I do is,

I calculate the $LHL$ and $RHL$ and f(1) and equate them to get the same equation, yes, i have the equation for continuity as my teacher.
$LHL$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\quad \lim _{x \rightarrow 1^{-}} (x^{2}+3 x+a) \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} (1+h^{2}-2 h+3-3 h+a) \\
=4+a
\end{array}
$$
$RHL$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1^{+}}(b x+2) \\
\lim _{h \rightarrow 0}(b+b h+2) \\
\quad=b+2
\end{array}
$$
Now,
$$
\begin{array}{c}
L H L=R H L \\
b+2=4+a \\
b-a=2   \hspace{10mm}. ..eq(1)
\end{array}
$$
Now solving for differentiability,
The same $LHD$,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\quad \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(1-h)-f(1)}{-h} \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1+h^{2}-2 h+3-3 h-4-2+2}{-h} \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h^{2}-5 h}{-h} \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0}(5-h) \\
=5
\end{array}
$$
And now $RHD$,
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{b+b h+2-4-a}{h} \\
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{b+b h-2-a}{h} \\
\text { Using } eq(1)... 
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{l}
=\lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{2+b h-2}{h} \\
=\quad b
\end{array}
$$
$$
b=5\\
a=3
$$

I used the right case for $f(1)$ that is,  $x^{2}+3 x+a$, for $x \leq 1$

So, $f(1)=4+a$,

So, who did this right, my teacher who used the $x>1$ case in the $RHD$, or me who used the actual $x \ leq 1$ case.

This is what I think, differentiability and continuity are related, as we know

> A differentiable function is always continous but not every continous function is differentiable.

So continuity is a much-needed required step to solve for differentiability, so I should solve for continuity first. As I did.

Anything just say? Is he right??

Comment: In general, suppose $f(x)$ is defined piecewise as $f(x) = f_1(x)$ when $x \leq x_0$ and $f(x) = f_2(x)$ when $x > x_0$.  Then, supposing that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both continuous and differentiable on their respective domains, in order for $f$ to be continuous and differentiable at $x_0$, we need $f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0)$, and also $f'_1(x_0) = f'_2(x_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

What you both did is correct when the problem says that the function is continuous then that means $x^2+3x+a$ must be equal to $bx+2$ so if you substitute $f(1)$ either of them they will be same intresting things happens when one of them doesn't contain $1$ in its domain then there comes limit operator but that's a different story. In this case $f(1)$ will be same whether you choose any of them because the function is continuous.

Here is a vague sense for it
$f'(x)=2x+3$ for $x\le1$
And
$f'(x)=b$     for $x>1$

For differentiable of $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ must be continuous so $b=5$ and further you can do yourself.

HOPE THIS HELPS.

Comment: I still get the vibes that putting f(1) not actually f(1) is wrong, while being possible.

Comment: Ok let's say if you get different value of f(1-) then from f(1+) then it says that function is discontinuous more precisely jump discontinuity. Check out jump discontinuity from some sources of your preference then see if it clears the doubt.

Comment: So, the last time I mean day before yesterday in a question in the RHD, he used the same concept for putting f(a) from x>a rather than x=a case. In the end he proved the function to be differentiable, while it wasn't, i checked the graph and it has a endpoint at that exact a point

Comment: The function is differentiable if a=3 and b=5 line 5x+2 is tangent to parabola $x^2+3x+3$ at point (1,7)

Comment: $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}x^{2}+3, x \leq 2 \\ 4 x+11,x>2\end{array}\right.$

Comment: This was the question, solve it using both the ways..